# php regex problem for direct speech

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find some direct speech with that expression in PHP:

`/Mr.X, (\"|\'|\'\')(.+?)(\"|\'|\'\') dedi\./`

//"dedi" means says in Turkish. 
First of all it works for that expression:

`Mr.X, "I will survive" dedi.`

But there is some problems that the expression matches like that one:

Mr.X, "**I will survive" asdasdasdasdasd Mrs.Y "so do I**" dedi.

How can I remove " characters in bold above?

Comment: Regex is typically not a very good idea for natural language parsing.

Comment: @mark natural language processing is typically not a very good idea, either

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I assume you mean NLP is too hard in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `(.+?)`, use `([^"']+)` to match only non-quote characters.

Answer (score 1):

This should work: `/Mr\.X, (["'])([^\1]+)\1 dedi\./U` Note the ungreedy modifier!
I'm not sure about the back reference in character class. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will indeed need some more powerful stuff than PHP.

For NLP tasks, you may use the GATE framework: http://gate.ac.uk/

For Direct speech tagging, the following GATE-related pages are useful:

http://www.rene-witte.net/reported-speech-tagging
http://www.semanticsoftware.info/reported-speech-tagger